# After Pytorch Upgrade , my model is giving almost random output

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I trained, tested and still using a model in "Pytorch 0.4.1". It was, and is still working fine (output is what it should be) if I use pitch 0.4.1.
But as i upgrade to version 1.0.1, every time, I try to evaluate same input image, I get different output (Its a regression).

I tried to see what has been changed in those versions, but since i am not getting any errors, warnings anything, i am not sure what should I look for specifically.

PS: I checked the weights, they are also same when I load the model

Comment: You need to provide more details, like your model and inference code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of drop out layer. Model.eval disables the dropout layer. Pretty simple.
But Now in Pytorh upgrade, if Dropout is not defined specifically in model **init** function, it will not get disable during eval. 
Atleast this was reason for my case.